# Impala not supporting Unicode characters

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera, impala

Select statement returning bad character on Impala.[image]
[image]
First image shows result by Hive and 2nd by Impala. It is managed table created in Hive, source table is external

Comment: Are you doing a substring or any string manipulation in your query to impala for this column?

Comment: @JNevill no I’m just executing select * from table

Comment: Generally speaking impala *can* store and display unicode, but it's pretty limited (which seems kind of dumb). Essentially it treats `STRING` as a byte array and so it only recognizes single bytes where unicode characters are 2, 3, or 4 bytes. So while it should store and display unicode (by accident), it can throw up all over itself in certain circumstances. [Here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_string.html) it says it will trip up during: *"String manipulation functions, Comparison operators, The ORDER BY clause. Values in partition key columns."*

Comment: @JNevill is there any work around?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, and this link helped me
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-UTF-8-problems/td-p/172558

On insertion use something like this

```
insert into test select 'привет' from test limit 1;
```